# Want to edit the input date and time inside the table. But if I am typing the 1st number it suddenly get triggered

Tags: javascript

Want to edit the input date and time inside the table. But if Iam typing the 1st number it  suddenly get triggered. Value should trigger after the date and time get entered.

The value will come inside the table. I need to edit the value inside the table.
For example:

```js
function myFunction() {

    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;

}
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"> </p>
```

Comment: Explain your `HTML` / Example first.

Comment: <td> <input type="datetime-local"  (change)="updActualDateRemovalCheck(care, $event.target.value); updateActualDateOfRemoval(care, $event.target.value);" value={{care.actualDateOfRemoval}}></td>

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to distinguish between [onkeyup](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) and [onchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) correctly.

The first triggers change after pressing and releasing a key, the latter when taking focus away from `input` with an actual changed value.

Comment: <input type="datetime-local" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
}
</script>  Can you please check this code.

Comment: Firstly, `oninput="myFunction"` (omit calling `()` the function when specifying handler). Secondly, try to play with different handlers, such as `onchange`.